# Issue with a multi dimensional array

Tags: c#, algorithm

I have 3 arrays. The first multidimensional (e.g. 5 rows and 6 columns) of messy positive integer values. The second array, therefore composed of 6 elements, corresponding to the value of the sum of the single columns of the first. the second, therefore composed of 5 elements, corresponding to the value of the sum of the single lines of the first. I need a function that shifts the values of the first array so that the sums of the columns and rows match the second array and the third array. Possibly without using external libraries.

try to write two functions, one fix the columns and one the rows. But doesn't work

Can you help me?

```
private void AdjustColumnOfSqueakyForFutureOnMatrix(decimal[,] matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance, List<InstanceQtyHolderItem> instanceQtyHolderItems, decimal[] totalByDP, int decimals)
{
    string matrixBeforeAdjust = GetStringViewOfMatrix(matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance);
    int mul = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < decimals; ++i)
    {
        mul *= 10;
    }
    decimal unit = 1 / mul;

    Logger.Info("Start Adjust Column for FutureOnMatrix");
    for (int j = 0; j <= matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
    {
        Logger.Info($"Try to Fix column {j}, rapresent element of InstanceQtyHolder idInstance: {instanceQtyHolderItems[j].IdInstance}, QtyHolder {instanceQtyHolderItems[j].QtyHolder}");
        do
        {
            decimal totalByColumn = SumByColumnOnFutureOnMatrix(matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance, j);
            Logger.Info($"Currently we have {totalByColumn} element on column {j}, expected {totalByDP[j]}");
            if (totalByColumn == totalByDP[j])
            {
                Logger.Info($"column {j}, correct");
                break;
            }
                
            bool isToAdd = totalByDP[j] - totalByColumn > 0;

            decimal maxValueOfColumn = 0;
            int rowOfMaxValueOfColumn = -1;
            for (int ii = 0; ii <= matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance.GetUpperBound(0); ii++)
            {
                if (matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance[ii, j] > maxValueOfColumn)
                {
                    maxValueOfColumn = matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance[ii, j];
                    rowOfMaxValueOfColumn = ii;
                }
            }

            if (rowOfMaxValueOfColumn == -1)
            {
                if (isToAdd)
                    rowOfMaxValueOfColumn = 0;
                else
                {
                    Logger.Warn($"In column {j}, there isn't a value that i can swap");
                    Logger.Warn($"Matrix, at the begin of the function {matrixBeforeAdjust}Matrix, at this moment {GetStringViewOfMatrix(matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance)}");
                    break;
                }
            }   

            decimal maxValueOfRow = 0;
            int colOfMaxValueOfRow = -1;

            for (int jj = j + 1; jj <= matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance.GetUpperBound(1); jj++)
            {
                if(SumByColumnOnFutureOnMatrix(matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance, jj) != totalByDP[jj])
                {
                    if (matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance[rowOfMaxValueOfColumn, jj] > maxValueOfRow)
                    {
                        maxValueOfRow = matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance[rowOfMaxValueOfColumn, jj];
                        colOfMaxValueOfRow = jj;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (colOfMaxValueOfRow == -1)
            {
                if (!isToAdd && j < matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance.GetUpperBound(1))
                    colOfMaxValueOfRow = j + 1;
                else
                {
                    Logger.Warn($"In column {j} there is value on row ({rowOfMaxValueOfColumn}) that i need to swap, but there isn't on another column with same row a value aviable to swap");
                    Logger.Warn($"Matrix, at the begin of the function {matrixBeforeAdjust}Matrix, at this moment {GetStringViewOfMatrix(matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance)}");
                    break;
                }
            }

            matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance[rowOfMaxValueOfColumn, j] += isToAdd ? unit : -unit;
            matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance[rowOfMaxValueOfColumn, colOfMaxValueOfRow] += isToAdd ? -unit : unit;

        } while(true);
    }
}

private void AdjustRowOfSqueakyForFutureOnMatrix(decimal[,] matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance, List<DeliveryPlanSaveEntity> sortedFutureDeliveryPlans, decimal[] totalByInstance, int decimals)
{
    string matrixBeforeAdjust = GetStringViewOfMatrix(matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance);
    int mul = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < decimals; ++i)
    {
        mul *= 10;
    }
    decimal unit = 1 / mul;

    Logger.Info("Start Adjust Row for FutureOnMatrix");
    for (int i = 0; i <= matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance.GetUpperBound(0); i++)
    {
        Logger.Info($"Try to Fix row {i}, rapresent element of DeliveryPlans id: {sortedFutureDeliveryPlans[i].IdDeliveryPlan}, idArticle {sortedFutureDeliveryPlans[i].IdArticle}, week: {sortedFutureDeliveryPlans[i].Week}");
        do
        {
            decimal totalByRow = SumByRowOnFutureOnMatrix(matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance, i);
            Logger.Info($"Currently we have {totalByRow} element on row {i}, expected {totalByInstance[i]}");
            if (totalByRow == totalByInstance[i])
            {
                Logger.Info($"row {i}, correct");
                break;
            }


            bool isToAdd = totalByInstance[i] - totalByRow > 0;

            decimal maxValueOfRow = 0;
            int columnOfMaxRowOfColumn = -1;
            for (int j = 0; j <= matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance.GetUpperBound(1); j++)
            {
                if (matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance[i, j] > maxValueOfRow)
                {
                    maxValueOfRow = matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance[i, j];
                    columnOfMaxRowOfColumn = j;
                }
            }

            if (columnOfMaxRowOfColumn == -1)
            {
                if (isToAdd)
                    columnOfMaxRowOfColumn = 0;
                else
                {
                    Logger.Warn($"In row {i}, there isn't a value that i can swap");
                    Logger.Warn($"Matrix, at the begin of the function {matrixBeforeAdjust}Matrix, at this moment {GetStringViewOfMatrix(matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance)}");
                    break;
                }
            }

            decimal maxValueOfColumn = 0;
            int rowOfMaxValueOfColumn = -1;

            for (int ii = i + 1; ii <= matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance.GetUpperBound(0); ii++)
            {
                if (SumByRowOnFutureOnMatrix(matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance, ii) != totalByInstance[ii])
                {
                    if (matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance[ii, columnOfMaxRowOfColumn] > maxValueOfColumn)
                    {
                        maxValueOfColumn = matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance[ii, columnOfMaxRowOfColumn];
                        rowOfMaxValueOfColumn = ii;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (rowOfMaxValueOfColumn == -1)
            {
                if (!isToAdd && i < matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance.GetUpperBound(0))
                    rowOfMaxValueOfColumn = i + 1;
                else
                {
                    Logger.Warn($"In row {i} there is value on column ({columnOfMaxRowOfColumn}) that i need to swap, but there isn't on another row with same column a value aviable to swap");
                    Logger.Warn($"Matrix, at the begin of the function {matrixBeforeAdjust}Matrix, at this moment {GetStringViewOfMatrix(matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance)}");
                    break;
                }
            }

            matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance[i, columnOfMaxRowOfColumn] += isToAdd ? unit : -unit;
            matrixOfQtysByDPAndInstance[rowOfMaxValueOfColumn, columnOfMaxRowOfColumn] += isToAdd ? -unit : unit;

        } while (true);
    }
}
```

Comment: `one [function to] fix the columns and one the rows` that may not work everywhere a solution is possible.

Comment: Can you add a minimal example of input and output you expect. It would help people more easily understand what you are trying to do,

Comment: What do you mean by `shifts` the values of the first array. Is that literally `shifts` the values in the linear representation of the array or `shifts` the columns and rows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question properly, you wish to permute the entries of the first 2-d array to have the row and column sums come out correctly.  This seems to be a very hard problem.  But I can outline the approach that I would follow for it.

First, you should check the obvious.  The sum of the first, has to match the sum of the second, has to match the sum of the third.  If they don't match, then the problem has no solutions and we need to no further work to prove it.

Assuming that the obvious check passes, there is a simple naïve algorithm to produce solutions.  Pick one spot in the array, we have 30 choices.  Try each one, then pick the next spot, we have 29 choices left.  Proceed recursively, checking constraints as you can.  This will work in theory, but it is way too slow.

The general rule in improving this kind of search is we want to follow two rules, and it is worth a lot of up front work to follow them.

1. Have as few choices as possible at each recursion step.
2. Try the most promising possibility first.

The idea of the first rule is to control the exponential explosion as much as possible.  The second rule is less important, but why waste energy looking where you don't think the answer is likely to be?

So what analysis lets us follow these rules?

First, we need to understand the [subset sum problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) in more depth than people usually consider it to be able to analyze our constraints.  Lay out all of our possible values from list 1 into an array.  Going forward, let's fill in 2 data structures going forward.

```
total_ways =
    by position before where we are in our array
        by number of elements in our subset
            by partial sum
                how many ways the partial sum can be this.

current_ways =
    by position in our array
        by number of elements in our subset
            by partial sum
                how many ways the partial sum can use the current element and be this
```

We can solve this forward using the rules:

```
total_ways[0][0][0] = 1
current_ways[i][j][x] = total_ways[i][j-1][x-array[i]]
total_ways[i][j][x] = total_ways[i-1][j][x] + current_ways[i-1][j][x]
```

where any lookups on data outside of our data structure give you 0.  And we only need to let `j` go in the range from 0 to the most terms we want in our sum, in this case 6.

This suffices for finding the number of subset sums.  It is a well-established algorithm that is what is known as pseudo-polynomial.  Meaning it is polynomial in the number of sums, which theoretically can be exponential in the number of input values.  But if the input values are all smallish integers, the number of sums will be limited, and performance is good.

But we want to know more.  How many ways are there to use a particular value in getting to a particular sum (say, for a row or column)?

To answer THAT kind of question, we also need to do the same algorithm backwards.

```
reversed_total_ways[len(array)][0][0] = 1
reversed_current_ways[i][j][x] = reversed_total_ways[i][j+1][x-array[i]]
reversed_total_ways[i][j][x] = reversed_total_ways[i+1][j][x] + reversed_current_ways[i+1][j][x]
```

And now how many ways are there to use element `i` in a subset sum of length `k` that adds to `c`?  It is:

```
sum over j in 1..k:
    over x in current_ways[i][j]
        current_ways[i][j][x] + reversed_total_ways[i][k-j][c-x]
```

With that in hand, our revised algorithm looks like this:

```
def finish_solution(remaining_values, partial_solution, list2, list3):
    if 0 == len(remaining_values):
        return partial_solution
    else:
        analyze subset sums up to length 6
        analyze reverse subset sums up to length 6
        for each column:
            find the which remaining_values can be used, with what counts
        for each row:
            find the which remaining_values can be used, with what counts
        of the open entries in partial_solution:
            find the one with the least possible values to use
        for the best open entry
            sort the possible values by decreasing fitness
                (where fitness is ways to finish column * ways to finish row)
            for each possible value:
                fill the open entry
                remove it from remaining_values
                answer = finish_solution(...)
                if finish_solution is not None:
                    return the answer
                else:
                    put the value back in remaining_values
                    empty the open entry
        return None
```

There are many variations, optimizations, and so on.  But if it is readily solvable this should be decently efficient.